# Make datepicker appear below input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been able to add the datepicker successfully but i want the calender to appear below the date input not above

HTML5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Jobportal - Login</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>

        <!-- Form Name -->
        <legend>Recruiter - Add Job</legend>

        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="txtjobtitle">Job Title</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="txtjobtitle" name="txtjobtitle" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="txtjobref">Job Reference</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="txtjobref" name="txtjobref" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">

            </div>
        </div>

         <!-- Date input --->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="date">Closing Date</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYY" type="text" required="">
            </div>
        </div>




    </fieldset>
</form>

<!-- Bootstrap Date-Picker Plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var date_input=$('input[name="date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
        var container=$('.form-horizontal').length>0 ? $('.form-horizontal').parent() : "body";
        date_input.datepicker({
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            container: container,
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
        })
    })
</script>


<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: $(function () {
        $("#fiscalYear").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",

    todayHighlight: true,
    orientation: "bottom auto";
        });
});

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
  $("#fiscalYear").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    orientation: "top" // add this for placemenet
  });
});
```

[Datepicker Orientation Doc](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#orientation)